# Group similar records by same ID in access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a table full of clients in access and some are similar to each other (eg. NBC6, NBC10, etc.) I was wondering if there was a way to group all the similar clients and assign them all 1 ID.  They would all start off the same so I was thinking to search for them like that but I'm unsure how to go about this in VBA.  I am rather new to access and SQL so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Look up [`Like` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg251796(v=office.14).aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new field in your table called ClientGroup.  Set its datatype to Text.

Get a list of all ClientGroup names you want to use.  Let's say, for example, that NBC6 and NBC10 should end up in one group called NBC.

Run an Update query to assign that group:

```
UPDATE tblClients
SET ClientGroup = "NBC"
WHERE ClientName LIKE "NBC*"
```

The asterisk sign acts as a wildcard, so it will only update the records where the first 3 letters of ClientName are "NBC".

It's a lot of manual work, I suppose if you know you always want to use just the first 3 characters of a ClientName you can write a loop to put them in an array, but that's probably not the case.